# Ultimate fate of Captain Hook in 1991's Hook movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, hook

In the 1991 movie *[Hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_(film))* (starring Robin Williams), what was the ultimate fate of Captain Hook? I know he was swallowed by the stuffed crocodile, but still, this **was** just a stuffed crocodile. It didn't have a working digestive system. And, I mean, sure, the crocodile "burped", but still... Just saying.

Normally, I would just chalk up this inconsistency to the writers, but I'm curious: is there perhaps any canon-based possible explanation? Maybe some of the magic exhibited by the children in Neverland did something?

Is it just the writers or am I on to something here? Just wondering what your thoughts might be on this.

Comment: It's a fantasy land where people have food fights with imaginary food, fly, and have fairies, mermaids and gigantic crocodiles... I think it's perfectly acceptable to think a stuffed croc could eat Hook and then burp.

Comment: Haha. Lol. Good point.

Comment: His hook even goes through the chestplating of the crocodile.. and magic green smoke comes out.. and then without moving its jaws it eats hook! Ok I get there can be no gore or blood but still.. I'd kind of imagine it using the hook as toothpick or something.

Comment: I actually love this question because even though it is kind of obvious what happens, I've always thought it kind of strange too.

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate fate of Hook is that he dies at the hands, or rather the jaws, of the crocodile, when it eats him, as per the original canon. There's no exposition offered as to why the crocodile awakens, but clearly it was still alive, in a magical coma. Like Sleeping Beauty.

Comment: What does the original play have to do with **Hook**? We all know that the crocodile is alive in **Peter Pan**, how does that relate to the presumed dead, stuffed crocodile in this film?

Comment: Hooks "relationship" w/the crocodile is a major part of the original story. They **had** to get Ol' Croc & the menace of his ticking belly into "Hook" somehow. After all, everyone knows that Croc gets Hook in the end. They wrote that part of things poorly. No one explains why he reanimates. You presumed he was dead, stuffed. I believe he was in a magical coma. Like Sleeping Beauty. We could go watch it again and come back with deeper answers. Or not (I know me. I'm going to go re-watch it in a while). Bye for now.

Comment: Tinkerbell generally raises the bar on magical possibilities enough that an animated stuffed crocodile is not that far-fetched. Keep in mind that this is a land where you never age and there is a magical fairy with an outspoken ability to perform magic. The croc did warrant some better explaining for cinematographical value, but the events themselves are not impossible either.

Answer (score -1):

He was crushed by the crocodile. How else could he have died? If it did not have a working digestive system, then Hook could have crawled out. It clearly crushes him, otherwise he would have been able to get out.